# Issues with PHP mail() function and HTML

Tags: php, html, smtp, phpmailer

I've been on the internet for more than 7 hours now and I still can't wrap my head around why is this happening.

Basically I have my **HTML** and **PHP** code in the same directory, my **HTML** contains a simple email contact form and my **PHP** is just a basic **mail()** function.

The issue comes when I try to send a message through the form ( after I've pushed it to the website ).

Nothing happens when I click my submit button, **BUT** if I go to [www.mysite.com/](http://www.mysite.com/) **mail.php** - my PHP file - it sends a blank email to the right email address so I figured that the issue is most definitely **not** with my **PHP** script.

Let me know if you can help. :)

**P.S.** Also, I know that I should've probably used **PHPMailer** or **Swift Mailer** and not just the default mail() function, but I don't really like the idea to have to use **gmail** for that.

mail.php:

```
<?php

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$subject = "Client Mail from ".$name;
$to = "clients@growpile.com";
$headers = "From: ".$email;
$txt = "You have received an e-mail from ".$name.". \n\n".$message;

mail($to, $subject, $txt, $headers);
header("Location: home.html?mailsent");?>
```

html:

```
                                        <!--CONTACT FORM START-->
                                    <form id="contact-form" class="fade-up" method="post" action="mail.php">
                                        <div class="row">

                                            <!--NAME FIELD-->
                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                <input type="text" id="cf-name" class="input__field cf-validate" name="name" placeholder="Name">
                                            </div>

                                            <!--EMAIL FIELD-->
                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                <input type="text" id="cf-email" class="input__field cf-validate" name="email" placeholder="Email">
                                            </div>

                                            <!--MESSAGE BOX-->
                                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                                <textarea id="cf-message" class="input__field cf-validate" rows="8" name="message" placeholder="Your Message"></textarea>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="alert-container col-md-12"></div>

                                            <!--SUBMIT BUTTON-->
                                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                                <button type="submit" id="cf-submit" name="submit" class="main-btn cursor-link">Send Message</button>
                                            </div>

                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                    <!--CONTACT FORM END-->
```

Comment: Please read [ask] with special attention to the bit about not posting pictures of code.

Comment: @Quentin Thanks! Edited it.

Comment: Using PHPMailer or SwiftMailer does not mean that you have to use gmail. Both can act as a front-end for the `mail()` function (which would avoid all the security vulnerabilities and formatting mistakes you're making), though SMTP to localhost is both safer and faster.

Comment: @Synchro thanks for the reply! Could you provide me with an example of that? :)

Comment: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer#a-simple-example plenty of others in the examples folder

Comment: @Synchro Thanks! Really appreciate your help!

Comment: Is your form action directing to the right page?

Comment: @bartholomew Pretty sure it is? It’s directing to ‘mail.php’ and ‘mail.php’ is in the same directory as the html.

Answer (score 0):

This code works.  Your spam filters are catching it or your email server is refusing the emails it sends.  I copied your code to my server and it ran exactly as you would expect and sent to my gmail but it went to spam.  Check your spam folder or send it to a different email address with looser spam restrictions to see the emails.